# How to access actions in the controller

Tags: sails.js

I'm a newbie trying to learn sails js, please bear with me.

As instructed in a tutorial I tried to set up my controllers and views to show a simple page just to make sure that the routing is working as expected.

So I have a PersonalController.js inside api/controllers folder. This was generated automatically from the generate cli command so I'm sure the location is correct.

Then I create a test view inside views/pages. I named it personal.ejs.

And so I modified my PersonalController to this

```
module.exports = {
  list: function(req, res) {
    return res.view('personal');
  }
};
```

I don't know why but I'm getting an error.

I tried to just return json but I still get the same result, 404.

```
module.exports = {
  list: function(req, res) {
    return res.json({
      todo: 'test'
    });
  }
};
```

I know I am missing something, just not sure what it is.

Comment: Just to add, when the api is already generated, when the controller is access it should at least return a blank list. But for my instances, it doesn't appear to be doing anything

Comment: did you generate just the controller ? what cli command did you use ?

Comment: yes. I ran "sails generate api personal"

Comment: what route are you calling ?

Comment: Have you set your config/blueprints.js  'actions' property to true?

Comment: no. now this is the reason. thanks for the comment.